# Samudra Manthan and Immortality

Tags: bhagavata-purana, samudra-manthan, immortality

I was reading stories of Samudra Manthan in Bhagavata Purana. It has been described that, Indra had insulted sage Durvasa and was cursed in return to loose all his material opulence.

That time, they also started losing battle with asuras and some devas getting killed in battle. Samudra manthan was done to extract nectar to make them immortal.

Following link says that, it happened in Chakshusha Manvantara, with Mantradruma as Indra.
http://vedabase.com/sb/8/5/en.

Does it mean that, previously all devas were NOT immortal?

What about in current manvantara ?

Comment: The gods are naturally immortal, then they temporarily lost their immortality due to Durvasa's curse, and they regained it by drinking Amrita.

Comment: The same link says "Durvāsā Muni immediately cursed Indra to be poverty-stricken, bereft of all material opulence" . It doesn't say they were cursed  to loose immortality

Answer (score 4):

The gods were mortal when they were born just as their brothers Asuras. However, they gained immortality even before drinking Amrita as is evident from the following verses from the **[Shatapatha Brahmana 2.2.2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1245.htm)**:

> 8. Now the gods and the Asuras, both of them sprung from Pragâpati, were contending with each other. **They were both soulless, for they were mortal, and he who is mortal is soulless. Among these two (classes of beings) who were mortal, Agni alone was immortal; and it was through him, the immortal, that they both lived. Now whichsoever (of the gods) they (the Asuras) slew, he, indeed, was so (slain).**
> 9. Thereupon the gods were left inferior. They went on praising and practising austerities, hoping that they might be able to overcome their enemies, the mortal Asuras. They beheld this immortal Agnyâdheya (consecrated fire).
> 10. **They said, 'Come, let us place that immortal element in our innermost soul! When we have placed that immortal element in our innermost soul, and become immortal and unconquerable, we shall overcome our conquerable, mortal enemies.'**
> 11. They said, 'With both of us is this fire (Agni): let us then treat openly with the Asuras.'
> 12. **They said, 'We shall set up (or, establish within ourselves, â-dhâ) the two fires,**--what will ye do then?'
> 13. They replied, 'Then we shall lay it down (ni-dhâ), saying, Eat grass here! eat wood here! cook pap here! cook meat here!' Now that fire, which the Asuras thus laid down, is this same (fire) wherewith men prepare their food.
> 14. **The gods then established that (fire) in their innermost soul; and having established that immortal element in their innermost soul, and become immortal and unconquerable, they overcame their mortal, conquerable enemies.**

Not sure which Kalpa or Manvanatar this happened but it seems that what Keshav mentioned in his comment could be right and they had lost their immortality after the curse of Durvasa which had to be regained through drinking Amrit. To answer the second part, yes they are immortal in the current Manvantar by virtue of having consumed the Amrit.

Comment: If the Apyas drank Amrita and became immortal, how does it extend to their birth as Adityas?

Comment: @Surya not sue if this incident relates to Apyas specifically that's why asked the other question. But there's also a Vedic verse which says gods became immortal after drinking Soma so clearly there have been different times when they attained immortality even before consuming Amrit.

Answer (score 2):

The devtas were born to Aditi, and so the law of the universe applied to them. "All things born must die." They were able to go against this law by drinking the amrit. However God was immortal. The devtas are not equal to god. They are rather the attendants of God who fulfill several necessary tasks in the God's absence.